# Filtering empty partitions in RDD

Tags: scala, apache-spark, filtering, rdd, partition

Is there a way to filter empty partitions in RDD? I have some empty partitions after partitioning and I can't use them in action method.

I use Apache Spark in Scala

Comment: why can't you use the partitions. Can you show the whole code and workflow? What kind of action does take only a partition into account?

Comment: check my answer with full example. only non empty partitions can be there as per example. now your action cant be applied on empty partitions as you requested

Comment: @UninformedUser I'm processing splitted files running another tools. I can't use empty partitions because tools throw exceptons: tool getting data from stdin and it throws exception while it's empty

Comment: @Patrice333 IMHO This then seems more like a problem of those tools then yours and should be addressed in those tools.

Answer (score 1):

From the little info you provide, I can think about two options. Use `mapPartitions` and just catching empty iterators and returning them, while working on the non-empty ones.

```scala
rdd.mapPartitions { case iter => if(iter.isEmpty) { iter } else { ??? } }
```

Or you can use `repartition`, to get rid of the empty partitions.

```scala
rdd.repartition(10) // or any proper number
```

Comment: I have to work on partitioned rdd, not partitions, so first option isn't good for me.
But 2nd - it increases processing time so much. I used colesce(), but it's not good for me

Answer (score 1):

This is my sample data

```
  val sc = spark.sparkContext
  val myDataFrame = spark.range(20).toDF("mycol").repartition($"mycol")
  myDataFrame.show(false)
```

***Output*** :

```
+-----+
|mycol|
+-----+
|19   |
|0    |
|7    |
|6    |
|9    |
|17   |
|5    |
|1    |
|10   |
|3    |
|12   |
|8    |
|11   |
|2    |
|4    |
|13   |
|18   |
|14   |
|15   |
|16   |
+-----+
```

In the above code when you do repartition on column then 200 paritions will be created since `spark.sql.shuffle.partitions = 200` in that many are not used or empty partitions since data is just 10 numbers (we are trying to fit 20 numbers in to 200 partitions means.... most of the partitions are empty.... :-))

1) *Prepare a long accumulator variable to quickly count non empty partitions.*
2) *Add all non empty partitions in to accumulator variable like below example.*

```
 val nonEmptyPartitions = sc.longAccumulator("nonEmptyPartitions")
 myDataFrame.foreachPartition(partition =>
    if (partition.length > 0) nonEmptyPartitions.add(1))
```

- drop non empty partitions (means coalesce them... less shuffle/ minimum shuffle ).
- print them.

```
val finalDf = myDataFrame.coalesce(nonEmptyPartitions.value.toInt)
println(s"nonEmptyPart : ${nonEmptyPartitions.value.toInt}")
println(s"df.rdd.partitions.length :  ${myDataFrame.rdd.getNumPartitions}")
println(s"finalDf.rdd.partitions.length  :  ${finalDf.rdd.getNumPartitions}")
```

print them ...

**Result** :

```
nonEmptyPart : 20
df.rdd.partitions.length :  200
finalDf.rdd.partitions.length  :  20
```

#### *Proof that all non empty partitions are dropped*...

```
  myDataFrame.withColumn("partitionId", org.apache.spark.sql.functions.spark_partition_id)
.groupBy("partitionId")
.count
.show
```

Result printed partition wise record count :

```
 +-----------+-----+
|partitionId|count|
+-----------+-----+
|128        |1    |
|190        |1    |
|140        |1    |
|164        |1    |
|5          |1    |
|154        |1    |
|112        |1    |
|107        |1    |
|4          |1    |
|49         |1    |
|69         |1    |
|77         |1    |
|45         |1    |
|121        |1    |
|143        |1    |
|58         |1    |
|11         |1    |
|150        |1    |
|68         |1    |
|116        |1    |
+-----------+-----+
```

***Note :***

- Usage `spark_partition_id` is for demo/debug purpose only not for production purpose.
- I reduced 200 partitions (due to repartition on column ) to 20 non empty partitions.

#### Conclusion :

*Finally you got rid of extra empty partitions which doesnt have any data and avoided un necessary schedule to dummy tasks on empty partitions.*

Comment: yeah, it's solution which I used. but my partitions are splitted files, so coalesce method increases processing time so much.

Comment: if you want to ignore empty partitions for your action as well as un necessary work for task. you have/should  to do coalesce or repartition(nonempty partitions)

Answer (score 0):

If you dont know the distinct values within the column, and wish to avoid having empty partitions, you can use `countApproxDistinct()` as:

```
df.repartition(df.rdd.countApproxDistinct().toInt)
```

If you wish to filter the existing empty partitions and repartition, you can use as solution suggeste by Sasa

OR:

```
df.repartition(df.mapPartitions(part => List(part.length).iterator).collect().count(_ != 0)).df.getNumPartitions)
```

However, in later case the partitions may or may not contain records by value.